# Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова «JOIN»

Tags: java, sql, join

Проверяла в СУБД - всё отрабатывает нормально. В NetBeans выдаётся ошибка:

> Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова „JOIN“

Код запроса:

```
String query = "SELECT Sale.date_sale, Cheque.quantity, Goods.price, Cheque.quantity*Goods.price" +
        "FROM Sale JOIN Cheque ON Sale.id = Cheque.id_sale JOIN Goods ON Goods.id = Cheque.id_goods" +
        "WHERE Sale.date_sale BETWEEN '2001-04-12' AND '2015-06-12' AND Goods.id = 1";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На первый взгляд проблема в конкатенации. У Вас пробела нет, к примеру тут:

```
Goods.price" + "FROM Sale
```

Надо так:

```
Goods.price " + "FROM Sale
```

Или так:

```
Goods.price" + " FROM Sale
```

То же самое и здесь:

```
Cheque.id_goods" + "WHERE
```

Comment: Вы правы, спасибо)

Comment: Сам о такие грабли ни раз спотыкался. :)